# Laravel 8 Sanctum SPA Auth - Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-page-application, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to implement Sanctum SPA Authentication. I'm getting the following error when trying to login (*only in production*):

`production.ERROR: Session store not set on request. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Session store not set on request. at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:483)`

Followed all the steps in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication). First calling `sanctum/csrf-cookie` GET request, then my API `login` POST request with the session cookie attached. Thank you for any tips!

My `login` method in `AuthController.php`, where the exceptioin is happening on line 28.

[image]

My `Http\Kernel.php` file with the middleweres for the API endpoints.

[image]

My API endpoint in `routes/api.php`

[image]

Comment: adding screenshot of text in questions is not good practice. Noone can copy/paste from it, search engines can't find anything in it.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

The authentication routes must be in the `routes/web.php` file.

Comment: That is not correct, using web routes just means you are using the web middlewere, you are not getting the benifits of the APIs then.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#how-it-works 
For this feature, Sanctum does not use tokens of any kind. Instead, Sanctum uses Laravel's built-in cookie based session authentication services. Typically, Sanctum utilizes Laravel's web authentication guard to accomplish this.

Answer (score 24):

Added `StartSession` to **app/Http/Kernel.php:**

```
protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ];
```

it worked for me.

Comment: It will more helpul if you paste de code instead paste an image

Comment: indeed adding screenshot of text in answers is not good practice. Noone can copy/paste from it, search engines can't find anything in it.

Comment: But why? Documentation doesn't say anything about it, why would I have to do it?

Comment: @Robert, I think it is because the `StartSession::class` is originally included only in the `protected $middlewareGroups` array, but not in the `protected $middleware` array where, in my case, the /login route belongs to. However, if I add the /login route to the `Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group`, another error will be shown because the /login route is not authenticated as yet.

Comment: this worked for me..

Answer (score 6):

To future you, the correct way to fix the issue is:

1. Publish Sanctum configuration

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"`

2. Inform your app/api middleware to utilize stateful sessions by adding `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` class on `app/Http/Kernel.php` under the correct route groups (api,web, e.t.c)

```php
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
...
```

**Following two steps are very crucial**

3. Add frontend domains/IP addresses that are allowed to utilize the Sanctum SPA sessions. This can be done either by adding `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` key in your `.env` file or modifying **stateful** key's value in the `config/sanctum.php` file.

4. For every request to the endpoints protected by sanctum middleware, it must include `origin` or `referer` header. Addittionally, include `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header if applicable.

Comment: I have all of this but weirdly rarery I still get the "session store not set" error.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 10.X in the case of SPA configurations, managed to solve this problem as per documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-configuration **without** adding `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` in middleware groups `'api'` of `app/Http/Kernel.php` as suggested in some comments.

What made it work for me was specifying an origin request header from the frontend that matched exactly any of the `app/config/sanctum.php` stateful domains defined in `'stateful'` config:

```php
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

An origin header that doesn't match will result in the error in the post.
Ensure to match request origin (or referer) header with `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` or `API_URL` in .env file as some commenters here have suggested. If you are including the port in your header, make sure to add it in `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` or `API_URL` config.

A config with `API_URL=http://localhost` for example will accept `origin='localhost'`  but not `origin='localhost:8000'`

**Additional Info:**

The error can stem from the `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` middleware failing a `fromFrontend()` check (because of the domain and config mismatch), which will not load necessary session middleware. A successful load will add `StartSession` middleware but includes other necessary middleware that might be missed if adding the middleware to `api` section directly.

Some more info from user dcon138 here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sanctum-throws-session-store-not-set-on-request?page=1&replyId=687773

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file check that `APP_URL={your app base url}` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```php
'api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // Add this line
],
```

`StartSession.php` is a session manager, that handle session from every API request.

Answer (score 0):

Added
`if (!$request->is('api/*') && $request->session()->all())`
in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`
The request was crashing due to the authenticate middleware checking for session, hence this helped.
P.S this fix for sanctum usage.